# Span jumps to new line even though it has inline-block?

Tags: html, css

So i've read multiple times that putting display:inline-block; in your span will fix it. But i just can't get it to work for me. Probably i just missed something, but i would like help on this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family:myRobotoRegular;
                src:url(fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family:myRobotoBold;
                src:url(fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf);
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family:myRobotoLight;
                src:url(fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf);
            }
            body {
                background-color:black;
                color:white;
            }
            h1 {
                font-family:myRobotoBold;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .right {
                float:right;
                width:49%;
            }
            .individual {
                height:100%;
                margin:0 auto;
                overflow-y:scroll;
                padding-right:10px;
                text-align:left;
                width:440px;
            }
            .bannerGreen {
                background-color:#0D731D;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .bannerTitle {
                font-family:myRobotoBold;
            }
            .bannerRarity {
                font-family:myRobotoLight;
            }
            .description {
                background-color:black;
                font-family:myRobotoRegular;
                padding:20px 10px 10px 10px;
            }
            .quotes {
                color:#C0B9A7;
            }
            .orangeStat {
                color:#F26A1C;
                display:inline-block;
                font-family:myRobotoBold;
                font-size:20px;
            }
            .yellowStat {
                color:#FFD30B;
                display:inline-block;
                font-family:myRobotoBold;
                font-size:20px;
            }
            .imgDiv {
                float:right;
                margin-top:-10px;
            }
            .img {
                height:58px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mainDiv">
            <div class="right">
                <div class="individual">
                    <h1>
                        CATEGORY
                    </h1>
                    <div class="bannerGreen">
                        <div class="imgDiv">
                            <img class="img" src="">
                        </div>
                        <span class="bannerTitle">
                            TITLE
                        </span>
                        <br>
                        <span class="bannerRarity">
                            SUBTITLE
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        DESCRIPTION
                        <span class="yellowStat">
                            STATISTICS
                        </span>
                        DESCRIPTION
                        <span class="orangeStat">
                            A STATISTIC
                        </span>.
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "A" in "A STATISTIC" should well be able to be on the first line, but instead it follows the entire span to the second line.

(Bonus points if you recognize this. ;) )

EDIT: Inline instead of inline-block surely fixes the problem, but then the period after the .orangeStat span jumps away from the span. And i'd like it to not jump away but i do not want it to be included in the span either. Is there a way to get that?

Comment: did you try to set `display:inline;` for `.orangeStat`?

Comment: @Banzay Yes, but when i do that, the period jumps away from STATISTIC, or whatever is placed behind it, and i do not want that as a standard. I also do not want that period to have the properties of .orangeStat

Comment: There's no need for inline-block in this case. You're just running out of space (.individual width).

Comment: @antesoles It's tight, but the letter A can definitely fit there. But when using inline, the period jumps away from the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want the A and STATISTIC to be treated individually, then you should put them in individual (inline-)block elements:

```
<span class="orangeStat">
    A
</span>
<span class="orangeStat">
    STATISTIC
</span>
```

**OR** (edit):

Use `inline` instead of `inline-block` and to remove the space between the STATISTIC and the period, try something like this:

```
<span class="orangeStat">
    A STATISTIC<!--
--></span>.
```

Comment: I do not wish for them to be individuals.

Comment: Then you will have a hard time to solve this :) Either you're using an inline-block that will be treated as 1 block element or you're using 2 - then you can expected them to be treated individually. That's how they work.

Comment: Well someone already gave a great solution to this, that being using inline instead of inline-block. Now i'd just like to get that period back in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the outer container

```
.individual {
    width: 490px;
}
```

The words are coming in second line because there is no enought space in the container.

**Or**

Decrease the font-size of yellowStat and orangeStat

Comment: Testing .orangeStat with inline instead of inline-block proves that the letter A has enough space to be placed on the first line.

Comment: Decrease the font size so that it can fit there?

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work with inline-block. I mean, i can only reduce it to the point where both words would end up on the first line. And using inline makes the period jump away from the span.

Comment: That's great, but that's not my desired result.

Comment: I feel either width of font-size variation can fix this without modifying the html.

Comment: I don't mind editing HTML or CSS, as long as it works. Which it does now.